# bash scripting taking integers as args and adding them

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting

so i have this code here:

```
    #!/bin/bash
sum=0
for i;
do 
   if [ "$i" -ge 0 ]
   then
       sum=$((sum + i))
   else
       sum=$((sum + (i * -1)))
   fi
done
echo $sum
```

so the user types blin.sh 1 3 2 5 -5 -8, and the program is supposed to take all of the integers, and make them positive, if it is a negative, and then echo the sum. but my bash code only echo's 0 for some reason unknown to science.

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: And why do you talk about command line arguments when your script looks at filenames instead?

Comment: file names?, how can i make it to where i takes in a integer??

Comment: Because the file names are included in the loop instead of the arguments..., stdin_data and stdout_data are both files that are in the same directory where you execute that script..., Do you know how to access the arguments/positional parameter in a bash shell script? The glob `*` expands to all files/directories in the current directory...

Comment: would you use "for i" instead?

Comment: You're already using that yes? remove the `in *` and try again.

Comment: no luck when i do echo $sum, it still says 0

Comment: But the errors are gone? or it is still there?, without the arguments that zero is expected...

Comment: yes the error has dissapeared

Comment: Add the arguments and try again....

Comment: what do you mean add the arguments? i don't understand,

Comment: Can you please execute script in verbose mode `set -x` and add output log in the original post by editing. This code looks fine and working for me in ubuntu.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by set -x?, when i execute the code that is currently posted it does nothing. except return a zero.

Comment: execute as `sh -x blin.sh 1 3 2 5 -5 -8` This will print all command execution on `stdout`

Comment: @thisisme : Can't reproduce your case. If I run your script as `bash blin.sh 1 3 2 5 -5 -8`, I get 24 printed.  You don't get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of your script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
for i ; do
   if [ "$i" -ge 0 ]
   then
      sum=$((sum + i))
   else
      sum=$((sum + (i * -1)))
   fi
done
echo $sum
```

The name of the script is `foo.sh`, Now execute that script with the arguments.

```
./foo.sh  1 3 2 5 -5 -8
```

Out put

```
24
```

Using `sh`

```
sh ./foo.sh  1 3 2 5 -5 -8
```

Out put

```
24
```

Using `dash`

```
dash ./foo.sh  1 3 2 5 -5 -8
```

Output

```
24
```

Using `zsh`

```
zsh ./foo.sh  1 3 2 5 -5 -8
```

Output

```
24
```

I don't see any errors there.

Answer (score 1):

use $* for all arguments (without the semicolon ;)

```
for i in $*
```

your code works for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for i in $*
do
        if [ "$i" -ge 0 ] 
        then
                sum=$((sum + i))
        else
                sum=$((sum + (i * -1)))
        fi
done
echo $sum
```

[image]

Comment: still nothing, it only returns zero, can you try it??

Comment: can you help me please?